# Assignment of property values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In AngularJS I have a problem that a variable is assigned a value of another object.
I have ng-table and this work fine

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" data-ng-init="getMeasureUnits()" class="table" >
<tr ng-repeat="measUnit in measureUnits" ng-click="oneEntity(measUnit)">
    <td data-title="'Id'" >{{measUnit.idUnit}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Name'" >{{measUnit.name}}</td>
    <td data-title="'abb'" >{{measUnit.abb}}</td>
</tr>
```

in Controller I have function oneEntity and I got one entity from table in function but can't be assigned to another entity that which I present it in another table.

```
$scope.measureUnitOne = {};
$scope.oneEntity = function(entity){
       $scope.measureUnitOne = entity;
        $location.path("/administration/edit/measureUnit.id");

};
```

After function I get fine location url I everything OK byt did't display the values in table :

```
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mesaureUnitName" data-ng-model="measureUnitOne.name" placeholder="Name">
...
```

Object {name: "Litar", abb: "l", last_update: 1441538332000, id_user: 123, idUnit: 2}

$$hashKey: "object:46"
abb: "l"
idUnit: 4
id_user: 123
last_update: 1441538363000
name: "Litar"
**proto**: Object

In first case when i Write values , table show values , in second case, that is what I got after function and noting show ... Can someone telm me where is problem ??

Comment: did't display the values in table  or  did't updated the values in table ?

Comment: Did't display in table. In function I got  object but after update object which I need to display , it's not same structure , like another type .. I write how looks like object before and after update..